# Outlook Redemption: attachment streaming

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I'm saving a lot of attachments in bulk using RDOAttachment.SaveAs however this seriously slows down the whole operation as they all have to go to disk first. Is there any way to stream them directly using IStream interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since IStream COM interface is not supported by all languages supported by Redemption.
You can use AsText or AsArray properties instead.

Comment: Thank you, I think AsArray almost suits. Can I maybe get IStream from attachment's mapi table with OpenProperty?